# Sitecore.Kernel Version 10.0.0 fails to Install from Nuget Manager

Tags: visual-studio, setup

I'm trying to install Sitecore.Kernel version 10.0.0 on Visual Studio 2019 solution running on .net framework 4.8 and I get following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to add reference. The package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Net.Http' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Based on the error it looks like it is an issue with dependency package `'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'` failing to install `'System.Net.Http'`

I tried the following to resolve the issue

1. Installed `'System.Net.Http'` on its own
2. Tried to install `'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'`, still I get the same error.

Any help around this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to see if manually adding `System.Net.Http` to the project references will solve the issue? You need to also verify the .net framework version in your project settings.

Comment: Are you installing without dependencies? In my opinion, that is the best way..

Comment: No, I tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was, its user error :(

When I created the ASP.Net Web Application Project, I missed selecting MVC as a option.

[image]

Once I removed the project and recreated it with MVC as a option, it allowed me to add Sitecore.Kernel as reference without any issues.